# java spring mvc cannot find uploaded file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have searched the tomcat 8.0 directory and it subdirectories but can't find the uploaded file, which was uploaded successfully.

Here is my upload code:

```
File folder = new File("Uploads");
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    BufferedOutputStream buff =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(folder+File.separator+f.getName()));
    buff.write(f.getFile().getBytes());
    buff.flush();
    buff.close();
    link = folder + File.separator + f.getName();
    }
    catch(IOException es){
        logger.info("error "+es.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: try printing to console/log folder.getAbsolutePath() and check that directory

Comment: Stupid me!  Thanks so much, Balaji

Answer (score 0):

As Balaji suggested, doing a simple Folder.getAbsolutePath() revealed it was being stored in the sts/sts-version/ directory.